# Clear all records from a store

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a store, I am loading records from it successfully. Now i need to clear all the records in it. How can i do this ?

```
myStore.remove(); // DID NOT WORK
myStore.clear(); // ENDED UP WITH AN ERROR TypeError: myStore.clear is not a function
```

How could i solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`myStore.loadData([],false);` is the solution.

Comment: No, it isn't. You are loading a "empty" data and suppressing the event. You must use "myStore.removeAll()"

Answer (score 10):

Remove will remove the records you pass in. You want removeAll as in `myStore.removeAll();`

Answer (score 10):

I find out that, at least on ExtJS 4.2.3, removeAll give an error the first time it is issued after a load. I got it resolved by doing:

```
store.clearData();
store.removeAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using version 2.0.12 and none of the above solutions worked. I read their readme.md and found `store.clearAll();`. 
That was my solution.